# how to match keywords/phrases in a text?

Tags: linux, node.js, text, text-analysis

I have...

- a *fixed* large set (about 1,000,000) of keywords and phrases, like `birthday`, `happy new year`, `vacation` etc.
- some *variable* text between 10 and 500 words.

I'd like to...

- identify those keywords/phrases that are present in the text (eg. `Hi John, happy birthday to you.` matches `birthday`), preferably with some information about number of equal matches
- tolerate grammar variations (`vacations` should match `vacation`, `countries` should match `country`) or "misspellings" (`nodejs` == `node.js`).

In essence something *similar* what Google does for searching (but they probably use way more complicated methods) or Stackoverflow does for tag matching / searching for answers.

Basically the user enters some text, and my program should do it's best to suggest relevant keywords.

In my case, the algorithm needs to operate mostly on English text, but should also be be applicable to other languages like German, Italian, French, Spanish, ...

Does some Linux / NodeJS library exist that can do that? Or at least a well-known algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

As for the first question you can simply read the whole set or line by line and make a String.match() against each word you need to search.

The second is a little trickier, you dont need the exact match but you need to calculate the similarity of 2 strings.There are many algorithms that can measure how similar two strings are. For example take a look at [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

There is a good library that implements all the above in node.js
https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural
It can tokenize the text, search for an exact or a similar word and also it implements [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) which is the simpler way a search engine can work!